# Integrate jQuery Intellisense in VS 2005

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2005

How to integrate JQuery Intellisense support in VS 2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't seem like it's possible.
See answer 10 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/18/jscript-intellisense-faq.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I just submitted a request to DevExpress - Refactor Pro and CodeRush - to create an add on for VS 2005.  If you and your associates go the DevExpress and make the request they may take heed and produce something.  Give it a try.